# PHP Arrays, referencing an earlier value in same array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I'm trying to do this

```
$system = array(
'key1'  => 'val1',
'key2'  => 'val2',
'key3'  => $system['key1'].'val3'
);
```

But when we echo key3 it ends up as just "val3" rather than "val1val3".

Is there a way around this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: $system is not an array at the moment you ask for index key1. The parameters are processed before the assignment operator here.

Comment: @Virus721 it might be an array, it might be some other type, it might be non-existent .. we can't say from the given snippet ... ;-)

Comment: $system is not an array - or has not index key1 - at the moment you ask for index key1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way around this problem?

You can assign it after you declare `$system`/`key1`:

```
$system = array('key1' => 'val1', 'key2' => 'val2');
$system['key3'] = $system['key1'] . 'val3';
```